# How do I change the root password on a remote machine with Net::OpenSSH?

Tags: perl, ssh, root, change-password

I want to change the root password on a remote Linux machine with a Perl script. My first try was the following code:

```
use Net::OpenSSH;
my $ssh = Net::OpenSSH->new(
    "linuxpc",
    user                  => "root",
    password              => "root",
    master_stderr_discard => 1
);
my @changepass = $ssh->capture(
    {
        stderr_discard => 1,
        stdin_data     => "newpw123"
    },
    "passwd"
);
print "Done\n";
```

But unfortunately it won't work. Could somebody help me please?

Comment: What, exactly, doesn't work? What happens when you run 'passwd' by hand? What error messages do you get?

Comment: The password change won't work. If I run passwd manually from command line on the remote linux pc I get the prompt to insert the new password. After pressing enter I get the dialogue to re-enter the new password.

Comment: Does it help if you change `stdin_data` to `newpw123\nnewpw123`?

Comment: No it does not help. :-(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Net::OpenSSH](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Net%3a%3aOpenSSH) distribution includes a sample script that does exactly what you want!

[change_passwd.pl](https://github.com/salva/p5-Net-OpenSSH/blob/master/sample/change_passwd.pl)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of discarding your errors, use `capture2`:

> ($output, $errput) =
>   $ssh->capture2(\%opts, @cmd)
>
> ```
> captures the output sent to both stdout and stderr by @cmd on the
> ```
>
> remote machine.

Quoted from [CPAN](http://search.cpan.org/~salva/Net-OpenSSH-0.52/lib/Net/OpenSSH.pm)

Also, might not be relevant, but perhaps use the full path to `passwd`. I am not sure whether a newline is added by the `capture` function, but it could be worth trying:

```
my @pwd = ("newpw123\n", "newpw123\n");
($output, $errput) = $ssh->capture2( { stdin_data = \@pwd }, "/bin/passwd" );
```

ETA: And of course, **check the errors** to see what's going on. Discarding errors while debugging is Bad Practice (tm).

ETA2: Try using the `--stdin` option for `passwd`, see if that helps. E.g.:

```
$ssh->capture2( { stdin_data = \@pwd }, "/bin/passwd --stdin" );
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried your solution but I got the error that the password for root is unchanged. I tried with newline and without but with no success.

Comment: @Stefan `\n` might not be the correct way to represent pressing the ENTER key.. not sure what might be. Instead of `capture` you might try `system`. Should be the same thing, but who knows.

Comment: Checking man passwd it seems there is a `--stdin` option. Perhaps that is your solution, changing to `"passwd --stdin"`

Comment: @TLP This passwd has no stdin option because it's a minimal linux system. :-(

Comment: Hmm, then my powers of deduction are failing. Some security option set? Such as, you have to enter your old pwd before changing to a new, so that `@pwd` above should be `@pwd = ( "root\n", "newpw123\n", "newpw123\n");`?

Comment: Thanks for you help. I found a script from the vendor of the device which can I can run via SSH to change the password.